# WSO2 ESB SSL handshake failure

Tags: ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-esb

I'm getting this error when trying to access a secure external service:

```
TID: [0]  [ESB]  [2016-01-07 11:08:52,310] ERROR -  I/O error: General SSLEngine problem {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1364)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1169)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:154)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.ssl.SSLClientIOEventDispatch.inputReady(SSLClientIOEventDispatch.java:241)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:340)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:318)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1703)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:278)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1338)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:808)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:806)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1301)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:171)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getFullLogMessage(LogMediator.java:184)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:91)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:230)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:218)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected end of input block; expected an identifier
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,13]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOB(StreamScanner.java:691)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMoreFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:1057)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextCharFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:802)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2917)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2814)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1062)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 30 more
```

The certificate was successfully imported by `keytool` and it appears on "Available Certificates" list.
The supported protocols and ciphers of the endpoint service are:

```
Supported versions: TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  TLSv1.0
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  (TLSv1.1: idem)
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
----------------------
[...]
----------------------
Minimal encryption strength:     strong encryption (96-bit or more)
Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
BEAST status: vulnerable
CRIME status: protected
```

Seems like it's a bug on ESB when trying to perform the handshake.
I'm using the `ESB-4.6.0`

**UPDATE**

The certificate was imported by:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias MyService -file /tmp/myservice.crt -keystore wso2carbon.jks
```

According Tharik's suggestion, the SSL handshake trace prints the following error:

```
[...]
***
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
%% Invalidated:  [Session-8, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
[2016-01-08 17:13:47,921] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1364)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1169)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
```

Comment: We recommend to use ESB Latest 4.9.0. Did you import it to default ESB trust store? Could you please enable SSL Handshake debug logs and share it. You can use following command to enable SSL Handshake debug logs.

sh wso2server.sh -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake

Comment: Hi Tharik. The upgrade now it's not possible due infrastructure restrictions. I'll enable the log and soon will post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.
In this case is that the ESB has a particularity which is a separated keystore for client-side operations. The correct import command is:

```
keytool -importcert -file <CERTIFICATE_FILE> -keystore <ESB_HOME>/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -alias "SomeAlias"
```

In other words, the correct keystore is `client-truststore.jks` instead `wso2carbon.jks`.

Comment: client-truststore.jks is the default trust store for WSO2 products and wso2carbon.jks is the keystore which has WSO2 product keys. We usually import third party keys to client-truststore.jks

Comment: **client** VS **server** keystores ....... Thanks, I wouldn't have guessed based on the docs